# Conditional expectation, multinomial and poison distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The number of goals team $A$ scores in a game described by a random variable $Z\sim Pois(\lambda)$. 
the goals distributed between 5 players (1 to 5) and the number of goals the $i-th$ player scored is $X_i$. in addition, if the total number of goals is $Z=z$ then
 $(X_1,X_2,...,X_5)|Z=z \sim Multi(z,p_1,p_2,...,p_5)$ .

a) calculate $E(Z|X_1=5)$

b) calculate $E(Z|X_1)$

my attempt:
$$ E(Z|X_{1}=5)=E(\sum_{i=1}^{5}X_{i}|X_{1}=5)\\=E(\sum_{i=2}^{5}X_{i}+5|X_{1}=5)\\=E(5|X_{1}=5)+E(\sum_{i=2}^{5}X_{i}|X_{1}=5)\\=5+E(\sum_{i=2}^{5}X_{i}|X_{1}=5) $$

When $Z=z$ :$$ X_{i}|X_{1}=5,Z=z\sim Bin\left(z-5,\frac{p_{i}}{\sum_{j=2}^{5}p_{j}}\right)$$

and then:
$$g(z) = 5+\sum_{i=2}^{5}E(X_{i}|X_{1}=5,Z=z)$$
$$ = 5+\sum_{i=2}^{5}(z-5)\frac{p_{i}}{\sum_{j=2}^{5}p_{j}}$$
$$ = 5+\left(\frac{(z-5)}{\sum_{j=2}^{5}p_{j}}\right)\sum_{i=2}^{5}p_{i}$$
$$ = 5+z-5=z$$

$$g(Z) = Z$$
$$E(Z|X_{1}=5) = E(g(Z))=E(Z)=\lambda$$

but clearly this is unreasonable since if $p_1$ is very small i would expect Z to get bigger. i guess i cannot conditional it on Z too.

any clue will help.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess $(X_1,X_2,...,X_5) \sim Multi$... actually means $(X_1,X_2,...,X_5 | Z=z) \sim $..., no?

Comment: correct. i have added it

Comment: is it still unclear?

Comment: BTW, that your result is wrong can also be seen by considering the case $\lambda<5$.

Comment: you are right. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Hint: The problem is that you are confusing $E(X_i|X_1)$ with $E(X_i|X_1,Z)$ 
To compute $E(X_i|X_1)$ you must first ask yourself about the distribution of $X_1,X_2$ - unconditioned.</s>

Edited: Forget the above, now the problem is elsewhere:

You are basically using $E[A]=E[E[A|B]]$ to write

$$E(X_i | X_1=5,Z)=\frac{p_i}{\sum_{j=2}^5 p_j}(Z-5)$$

$$E(X_i | X_1=5)= \frac{p_i}{\sum_{j=2}^5 p_j}(\lambda-5)$$

which is wrong (see that it is absurd when $\lambda$<5), because the last expectation should be taken considering that you know $X_1=5$, which would influence $Z$. (You really should write, instead of $\lambda$, $E(Z|X_1=5)$ ... but this would give you a tautology; this is not the way).

---

The above shows the error in the derivation. How to solve it? One way is to deduce the full probability of the unconditioned $X_1,X_2...$ is a set of independent Poisson with $E(X_i)=\lambda p_i$. Then $E(X_i|X_1=5)=E(X_i)=\lambda p_i$ and $E(Z|X_1=5)=5 + \lambda (1-p_1)$

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: well when i write in words "When Z=z" i mean conditioned by Z=z. just as with your first comment...

Comment: i have edited it to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Ah, I see that you've edited it, let me see it.

Comment: why? cant i depend a dependent variable? lets say i call it $Y=(X_i|X_1=5)$ then i look on $Y|Z=z$

Comment: See correction.

Comment: i agree this is absurd. and i have thought about that but i dunno if its defiantly wrong since if i depend on a impossible scenario like $X_1=5, Z<5$ then i depend on $\phi$ and this should give me expectation of zero no? any way i agree there is a problem with my solution since i know its unreasonable and i suspect that depending it on Z is probably the problem as i wrote on the question, but what should i learn from this? that you cannot depend a dependent variable? or you cannot use the total expectation in that scenario?

Comment: how come $X_1,...,X_5$ are a set of independent Poisson? they are dependent variables no?

Comment: You can apply total expectation, but you cannot ignore the other contioning.  $E(g(Z))$ should be taken not with respect to the unconditioned $Z$ but with respect to $Z|X_1=5$

Comment: Independent Poisson variables conditioned to the sum gives (dependent) multinomial variables, check it.

Comment: excuse me... i dont understand why $E(X_i|X_1=5)=E(X_i)$? what is the justification ? guess i dont understand you previous comment.

Comment: i got it! thank you very much! it was very helpful!